# Confusing concepts in proof of spherical addition theorem

Tags: coordinate-systems, rotation, spherical-harmonics

In

http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116C/SphericalHarmonics_12.pdf,

section 4, pages 6..9 is a proof of the spherical harmonics
addition theorem.

Page 8 has eq.(25), an application of Laplace series:

$$Y_{lm}^*(\theta,\phi) = \sum_{m'=-l}^{l} B_{mm'}
Y_{lm'}(\gamma,\beta).$$

This is just very confusing.  I sort of get the idea of what
$Y_{lm}^*(\theta,\phi)$  is.  It is simply the usual spherical
harmonic but just relating it to the vector  $\vec{r}$  i.e.
if we play around with $\vec{r}$  and let it point all different
ways, and create a function that outputs the usual spherical
harmonic tortoise shell values as $\vec{r}$  moves around..

But what is  $Y_{lm'}(\gamma,\beta)$  on the right
hand side?  When you offset  $\vec{r}$  from  $\vec{r}'$
which is how you get $\gamma$   ($\gamma$ being defined as
the angle between  $\vec{r}$  and  $\vec{r}'$  on page 7)
then I guess
we can define a spherical harmonic type function over the
coordinates  $(\gamma,\beta)$  analogously, but  $\beta$  is
arbitrary!  When we line up  $\vec{r}'$  with the $+z$ axis
(creating a new coordinate system)  we
pick some $x$ and $y$ axes to go with the new coordinate system,
but that choice is arbitrary and determines $\beta$.

Can anyone explain more sensibly what's going on here?

Comment: Yes $\beta$ is ``arbitrary'', but if you continue to follow his proof you see that he integrates over the solid angle, so $\beta$ integrates out in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What he's really trying to say in eq.(25),

$$Y_{lm}^*(\theta,\phi) = \sum_{m'=-l}^{l} B_{mm'}
Y_{lm'}(\gamma,\beta)$$,

is  "Given the complex conjugate of an e.g. $l=l_0=10,m=m_0=+7$
tortoise shell  (spherical harmonic), there exists a set
of 21 coefficients  (the $B$s)  that constitute a linear combination
of the 21 tortoise shells of $l_0=10$ but TILTED,
such that this linear combination of TILTED tortoise shells
sums to the original  'right side up'  spherical harmonic  $Y_{lm}^*(\theta,\phi)$."

This is a result of Laplace series.

Fine, but then he says  "Now set $\gamma \rightarrow 0$
and we can solve for $B_{m_0=+7,m'=0}$"   (because all
the $B$s with $m' \neq 0$ go away).

<strike>But by his definition  (see page 7), to say $\gamma=0$  means the
right hand side $Y$s  are not tilted at all with
respect to the left hand side $Y$!</strike>

So the statement

${Y^*}_{l_0=10}^{m_0=+7} = B_{m_0=+7,m'=0} \sqrt{\dfrac{2l+1}{4\pi}}$

(see his work after eq.(27) on page 8)
does not make sense to me.  How could a
$m_0=+7$ spherical harmonic = a constant?